# How to redirect after successful saga api call

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I'm using React 16

This button

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitTechnologyHandler}>
    <div className = "row">
        <Button variant="contained" type="submit" >
            Create
        </Button>
    </div>
</form>
```

calls

```
submitTechnologyHandler = ( event ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
...
    this.props.onNameChanged(technology);
}
```

with

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onNameChanged: (technology) => dispatch(actions.createTechnology(technology))
    };
};
```

createTechnology is an action creator

```
export const createTechnology = (technology) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ADD_TECHNOLOGY_START,
        technology: technology
    }
};
```

This Saga is executed as a result:

```
export function* newTechnology(action) {
    try{
        const response = yield axios.post("/tech/", action.technology);
        yield console.log("saga/newTechnology", response.data);
        yield put(actions.addTechnology(response.data));

        here I would like to redirect to ('/tech/' + response.data.seoName); if successful
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

addTechnology updates the store:

```
export const addTechnology = (technology) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ADD_TECHNOLOGY,
        technology: technology
    }
};
```

and

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_TECHNOLOGY:
            return updateObject(state, action.technology);
```

So How Can I Redirect to a url in Saga or Reducer. Because I get an id from the server and I must use that to redirect?

Comment: Which routing package are you using in your project?

Comment: "react-redux": "7.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
        "react-router-last-location": "2.0.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
        "redux": "4.0.5", I can add any package that can fix this

Comment: @usertest Is [window.history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) not an option?

Comment: @HMR tried it, it only change the url it didn't cause React to load the route component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it using `connected-react-router` package

Step 1: Reducer

```
src/redux/rootReducer.js
import {connectRouter} from 'connected-react-router'
export const rootReducer = history => combineReducers({
   router: connectRouter(history),
   technology: technologyReducer
});
```

Step 2: Store

src/redux/store.js

```
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

export const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/metro' });

const middleware = [
  ...getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
    thunk: true
  }),
  sagaMiddleware,
  routerMiddleware(history)
];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer(history),
  middleware,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  enhancers: [reduxBatch]
});
```

Step 3: Apply ConnectedRouter

src/app/App.js
Replace BrowserRouter with ConnectedRouter

```
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'connected-react-router';
import {history} from '../redux/store'
<Provider store = {store}>
   <ConnectedRouter history = {history} >
      <PersistGate persistor = {persistor} loading = {<LayoutSplashScreen/>}>
         <React.Suspense fallback = {<LayoutSplashScreen/>}>
               <MaterialThemeProvider>
                  <I18nProvider>
                     <Routes/>
                  </I18nProvider>
               </MaterialThemeProvider>
         </React.Suspense>
      </PersistGate>
   </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Usage

Saga: src/dev_road/store/sagas/technology.js

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
export function* newTechnology(action) {
   try{
      const response = yield axios.post("/tech/", action.technology);

      yield put(actions.addTechnology(response.data));

      yield put(push(`/technology/${response.data.seoName}`));

   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
   }
}
```

https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using react-router for routing, you can use react-router-redux to sync routing with redux store.

This article explains it with a simple example - https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/react-router-redux-app-with-call-to-api-70a324c34ecb